# Redirect after validation done jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to redirect to another page after all the fields in the form are validated. I am doing this in CSS. I want to trigger a redirect method after validation in CSS.

I saw in net we can make use:

```
window.location = "https://www.asdfg.com" //Something like this

<style>
div.selectBox
{position:relative;display:inline-block;cursor:default;
text-align:left;lineheight:30px;clear:both;color:#888;}
span.selected
{width:167px;text-indent:20px;border:1px solid #ccc;border-right:none;border-top-left-radius:5px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:5px;background:#FFFFFF;overflow:hidden;}
 span.selectArrow
 {width:30px;border:1px solid #FFFFFF;border-top-right-radius:4px;border-bottom- right-radius:4px;
 text-align:center;font-size:20px;-webkit-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none;user-select: none;background:#FFFFFF;}

span.selectArrow,span.selected
```

{position:relative;float:left;height:30px;z-index:1;}

```
div.selectOptions
{position:absolute;top:28px;left:0;width:198px;border:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom-      right-radius:5px;
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;overflow:hidden;background:#FFFFFF;padding-top:2px;display:none;}

span.selectOption
{display:block;width:80%;line-height:20px;padding:5px 10%;}

span.selectOption:hover
{color:#ffffff; background:#4096ee;} 
</style>

<body>
<h1>Registration form</h1>
<form id=payment>
<fieldset>
<legend>Account Information</legend>
<ol> 
<li><input id=name name=name size="40" type=text placeholder="User Name" required autofocus></li>
<li><input id=email name=email type=email placeholder="Password" required></li> 
<li><input id=phone name=phone type=tel placeholder="Verify Password" required></li> 
</ol>
</fieldset> 

<fieldset>
<legend>User Details</legend> 
 <ol> 
 <li><input id=name name=name type=text placeholder="First Name" required autofocus>   </li>
 <li><input id=name name=name type=text placeholder="Last Name" required autofocus></li>
 <li><input id=name name=name type=text placeholder="Email ID" required autofocus></li>
 <li><input id=email name=email type=email placeholder="Company" required></li> 
 <li><input id=phone name=phone type=tel placeholder="Telephone No" required></li>
```

Select Country
      
      [Select Country]
      India
      Singapore
      US

```
 </div>
 </li>
 <li> 
<button type=submit>Register</button>
</fieldset> 
</form> 
</section>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: "after validation in CSS" What do you mean? Validation is done in javascript/jquery, not in CSS. Post your logic of validation, please.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like

html:

```
<input type="button" id="registerbutton" value="Register" />
```

js:

```
$("#registerbutton").click(function () { register(); });


function register() {
    $("#myform").validate();

    if ($("#myform").valid()) {
        window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
    }
}
```

If you want to post the form I think you'll have to do it with $.ajax and redirect on success callback. Also get your concepts right and see roasted's comment.

Comment: Hey , Thank You sormii .I got it